# How to get all values from Jlist?

Tags: java, swing

I have to find the longest word for each value from Jlist, not only a selected one. How do I get all values, without selecting anything?

I have the list defined :

```
list = new JList<String>(model);


btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // Run
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String intxt = "", extxt = "";
                intxt = list.getSelectedValue();
                if (intxt == null) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No chosen value", "Error",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    ...
```

Comment: Note that JScrollPane has ***nothing*** to do with your question or your problem. You're getting the data from a JList (its model, actually) which just happens to be held by a JScrollPane.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post some sample values from your `model` and indicate _the longest word for each value_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop in its `ListModel` and call `getElementAt(int index)` method:

```
JList<String> list = new JList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
    String listElement = list.getModel().getElementAt(i);

}
```